# save the user input to existing text file everytime running the script python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to save the user input into one text file(I want to keep the record for a month).

But I'm not sure how to keep the old user input because every time I re-run the script new user input is automatically written on old-user input.

Is there any way to keep all the records regardless of running the script?

This is a simple example.

When I run the script once, I get the following result in output textile,

```
2.5 2015-07-30
7   2015-07-30
1   2015-07-30
4   2015-07-30
5   2015-07-30
8.9 2015-07-30
```

but when I re-run the script, the above data is all being written by new user input. How can I make it so that my output text file maintains all the record regardless of running the script? 
This is my desired look of my output text file

```
2.5 2015-07-30
7   2015-07-30
1   2015-07-30
4   2015-07-30
5   2015-07-30
8.9 2015-07-30
4   2015-07-31
7   2015-07-31
2.4 2015-07-31
5   2015-07-31
1   2015-07-31
```

and this is the code that I've tried so far.

```
import datetime

with open("output.txt", 'w') as textfile:
    while True:
        input = raw_input("Enter: ")
        if input == 'done':
            break
        textfile.write(input+'\t'+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime("20%y-%m-%d")+'\n')
```

Comment: Have you checked the [relevant tutorial section](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [open the file in append mode](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) to preserve the data already in the file.

`'a'` opens the file for appending.

`'a+'` opens the file for appending and creates the file if it does not exist.

```
import datetime

with open("output.txt", 'a+') as textfile:
    while True:
        input = raw_input("Enter: ")
        if input == 'done':
            break
        textfile.write(input+'\t'+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime("20%y-%m-%d")+'\n')
```